# Cucumber parallel execution against a website which requires a login but doesn't allow multiple sessions using the same profile

Tags: java, mongodb, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I'm currently reworking/improving some regression suites that run in Jenkins, and one of the main improvements I want to make is to reduce test times, parallel execution is one of the obvious solutions to this. However, the issue is that the tests are for functionality within a site that requires the user to logon, but doesn't allow multiple logons of the same profile to be active.

i.e. if I signed in to the website on one machine with ProfileA, then signed in on a separate machine with the same profile, as soon as they try to complete any action on the first machine, the user is presented with a message advising that another session has been created with their profile, so they have been logged out for security.

This causes an issue in that if the tests that are running in parallel try to use the same profile it will cause failures.

The solution I am currently looking at is simply assigning a different profile to every scenario, so there is no chance of this occurring, however this could quickly become unmanageable due to the number of scenarios that currently exist and any others that may be added in the future. There are other restrictions around creation of these profiles in our test environments for various reasons.

I've tried implementing a system where the framework contains smaller amount of profiles and the tests simply look into the list of profiles and select one that matches the criteria for the profile needed for the test, however I haven't been able to find much info on how to make it so that it's impossible for a profile already in use to be selected from the list (some kind of check in/out system) which is the issue I'm hitting. Any suggestions on how to implement this either using java, or via some other tooling? (MongoDB seems like it may have something like this that could be used, but I'm new to mongo and haven't been able to find anything unfortunately)

Comment: You can put all profiles into a static blocking queue. Take one out at the start of a scenario, put it back in at the end. The queue will block when no elements are available. When elements are returned the queue will unblock. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: But honestly, ideally you create and delete profiles via an API. Anything else is a waste of time.